# Maintaining "Save to" folder for print-to-pdf files

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pdf, printing

I need to document my work by printing files/pages to a PDF which creates an emailed link in my Microsoft Outlook inbox.  I open the newly created PDF file via clicking a link (not an attachment) and then save them to a shared drive.  The problem is, each time I go to save a new PDF, I have to navigate through all my subfolders to find the ultimate location that I wish to save to.  How can I make it so that it defaults to the last place I saved to?

Answer (score 2):

Map a drive letter to the network location you save the files to.  That way instead of having to navigate through the sub folders you can just select the drive letter.